# Side of triangle problem

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, $AB=BC=12$. Side $AC$ extended through $C$ a length equal to itself to a point $D$. Point $E$ is on $AB$; $DE$ intersects $BC$ at $F$ and $BF$ equal to 8. Find $AE$ without using the centroid.

Comment: Suggested use of similar triangles.

Comment: What do you mean without using the centroid?

Comment: Are you familiar with vectors?

Comment: I know that this can be solved by showing that F is the centroid, but it's suggested that we solve using similar triangles.

Comment: I know a little bit.

Comment: F lies on BC. How can it be centroid?

Comment: @Awesome F could be the centroid of triangle ADB, then E and C would be midpoints of AB and AD respectively, and the numbers will work out.

Comment: Okay... ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Draw CP // AB.

[image]

$\triangle DPC$ is similar to  $\triangle DEC$

Then, AE = (0.5)PC

$\triangle FPC$ is similar to  $\triangle FEB$

Then, EB = (0.5)PC

Therefore, AE = EB = (0.5)AB = ... = 6

Comment: how do we know that EB is half of AB?

Comment: AE = (0.5)PC = EB. Then, AB = AE + EB = EB + EB = 2EB.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you directly see similar triangles, vectors is always the best approach at these kinds of things. An answer, unlike geometrical approach, is always guaranteed.

Assume $B$ at origin. Vectors $\vec a,\vec c$ are $\vec {BA},\vec{BC}$

All are vectors below :

$CA=\vec c-\vec a$

$BD=\vec c+\vec  c-\vec a$

$BF=\frac{8}{12}\vec c $

$DF=BD-BF$

Assume $\vec{BD}+x\vec{DF}=y\vec {BA}$

Where $x\vec{DF}=\vec{DE}$ and $y\vec{BA}=\vec{BE}$
Compare magnitudes of $\vec a$ and $\vec c$
 on both sides as they are independent.